# Have some Confusion in timer of C

Tags: c, linux, timer

I want to make one timer which calls my function after a certain interval and then continues.
Whenever my specific process will complete, then I want to stop this timer.
Here I have one function which I want to call after certain time but I want to pass parameters in this function.

My questions are below regarding this topic.

1. How can I pass parameters to this function?
2. Is There any way to achieve this goal.

Currently I am using this code. Please read my code comments which I wrote in between code so you can get idea about my goal.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
    int result = 10;
    int i =0;

    // here I make timer which calls getP() function and I want to pass some
    // parameter to my getP function from here.
    // I don't want to make these variables global.
    initSigaction();
    initTime();
    // other process thread. If this process will be completed then I have to stop timer.
    pauseTime();
}

void initSigaction(void)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = getP;//;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGPROF, &act, NULL);
}

void initTime(void)
{
    struct itimerval val;
    //printDebugLog(WIFI,"Timer value : %d",TIMER);
    val.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    val.it_interval = val.it_value;
    printf("\nProgress Timer started\n");
    setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &val, NULL);
}


void getP()
{
    // I want to get some parameter from main function and want to do some
    // calculation on this.  How can I get that parameter?
    printf("HI Hello");
}

int pauseTime(void)
{
    struct itimerval val;
    val.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    val.it_interval = val.it_value;
    setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &val, NULL);
    printf("\n Stop Progress Timer\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a step back here; the set of functions which you can safely call in a signal handler is very limited - see [signal(2)](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?2+signal).

One tactic is simply to increment a variable (of type sig_atomic_t) in your signal handler, and to check for this flag elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In `signal.h` on my Linux system the type `sighandler` is defined as:

```
void (*__sighandler_t) (int)
```

That means `sighandler` (`getP()` in your example) has to be a pointer to a function returning `void`. An `int` is passed to it -- the signal number. So there's no way to get the signal library to pass any other parameters to `getP()`.

This looks like a case for globals.

Comment: Is there any provision to pass parameter up to my getp() function?

Comment: No; there is no provision for passing arbitrary data to a signal handler.  You inevitably end up using variables defined outside of any function, either global or static.  Also, there are strict limits on what it is safe to do in a signal handler.  Standard C allows almost nothing; POSIX allows some functions to be called, but not many (and `printf()` is not amongst the safe set).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How can i Stop this timer . Here i am using pauseTimer Function to stop this timer, its right way to do this? or we have to set default value of signal?